# How to remove ffmpeg artifacts in the output timelapse video?

Tags: ffmpeg

I used a number of jpeg files to create a timelapse video with `ffmpeg`. Individually they are visually ok.

These source images are captured by a mirrorless DSL camera in JPEG format.

If I upload the  timelapsevideo to youtube, the video is clear and without any artifact: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Qs-1ahCrb0Y

However if I play the video file locally on MacOS in Photo or Quicktime apps or in iOS, there are artifacts in the video. Here are some of the examples:

1.

[image]

2.

[image]

This is the `ffmpeg` command I used to generate the video:

```
ffmpeg -framerate 30 -pattern_type glob  -i  "DSCF*.JPG" -pix_fmt yuv420p -profile baseline  output.mp4
```

What additional parameter I can use to remove those artifacts?

**Edit:**

1. File info

[image]

2. The video plays without issue in VLC.

Comment: Does it happen in VLC? What's the resolution?

Comment: It does not happen in VLC. Resolution will be added to the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The H.264 codec standard defines [levels](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Video_Coding#Levels). The level represents the resources required by a decoder to smoothly process a stream. Usually, levels are only pertinent for hardware players. However, some software players may have been designed with a level ceiling. Apparently, that's the case with Apple's players.

Your video's frame size is 6000x4000 for which the player has to support level 6.0, which is a recent addition to the standard (~2 years). I suggest you halve the resolution,

```
ffmpeg -framerate 30 -pattern_type glob -i "DSCF*.JPG" -vf scale=iw/2:ih/2,format=yuv420p -profile baseline out.mp4
```